# jQuery animate scroll

Tags: jquery, user-interface, scroll, effects

I'm not sure how to call the effect, but can someone point me into a library that would help me do the same effect as this website?

http://www.makr.com

Basically, it moves up the row to the top of the page on mouse click.  A code snippet, preferably jQuery, can help to, if there is no such specialized effect library for it.

Im not sure if i need to start another topic, but can anyone help me with a small jQuery snippet to achieve the whole effect of the Makr UI?

Comment: Im not sure if i need to start another topic, but can anyone help me with a small jQuery snippet to achieve the whole effect of the Makr UI?

Comment: I gave you something good to start with. When you click on an item, get the offset off that item en scroll to the offset with jQuery animate.

Comment: yes i got them, I was able to scroll them up, but im having trouble with the next part of the animation of slideDown. i cannot quite achieve timing them the way Makr does.

Comment: You can alway use the delay-function: .delay(1000) to delay the function 1 second. http://api.jquery.com/delay/
Or set the slideDown in the complete function

Answer (score 222, accepted):

You can animate the scrolltop of the page with jQuery.

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(".middle").offset().top
 }, 2000);
```

See this site: 
http://papermashup.com/jquery-page-scrolling/

Comment: I've only needed to use `#("body").animate(...);` and it worked for firefox, chrome, and ie. Is there a specific case for also attaching the animation to the `html` DOM object?

Comment: The '$(".middle").offset().top'-part is to get the offset of that object (class,id,...), so the page knows what height to scroll to. If you want to scroll to a certain div that is located half-way the page, this can be usefull.

Comment: `$('html, body')` is for ie8 compatibility.

Comment: $('html, body') is also for safari

Comment: how exactly does jQuery achieve smooth scroll?

Comment: In 2021 $('body') does not work in Chrome nor Firefox, only $('html') does. So of course the way to go is: `$('html, body')`. By the way none of these work either: $(window), $(window.document), $(window.document.body)

Answer (score 5):

You can give this simple jQuery plugin ([AnimateScroll](https://plugins.compzets.com/animatescroll/)) a whirl. It is quite easy to use.

**1. Scroll to the top of the page:**

```
$('body').animatescroll();
```

**2. Scroll to an element with ID `section-1`:**

```
$('#section-1').animatescroll({easing:'easeInOutBack'});
```

*Disclaimer: I am the author of this plugin.*

Answer (score 1):

I just use:

```js
$('body').animate({ 'scrollTop': '-=-'+<yourValueScroll>+'px' }, 2000);
```

Comment: can you explain what are you trying to do with the '-=-'? are you trying to typecast the number or something?

Comment: @user151496 Take a look at jQuery's documetation http://api.jquery.com/animate/ under the paragraph that currently starts "Animated properties can also be relative." Just like in JS you can say `myVar += 10` to add ten to an existing value, this snippet is basically using jQuery's custom parsing to effect a similar goal: `scrollTop -= -yourScrollValue`. I cannot say for sure why the OP here chose that over a simpler `{scrollTop: '+= '+value}`.

Comment: @user151496 the first '-' is decrease value and the second '-' if meet value negative they become to positive and opposite. :)

Comment: i understand what -= and - does. i just don't know why wouldn't he use += instead :S

Comment: @user151496 if use += maybe in case scroll go down instead go up that he want. :)

Comment: that's seriously some weird logic

Comment: What kind of language program that you use for this? :), I'm use asp and I visit here :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var page_url = windws.location.href;
var page_id = page_url.substring(page_url.lastIndexOf("#") + 1);
if (page_id == "") {
    $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: $("#scroll-" + page_id).offset().top
    }, 2000)
} else if (page_id == "") {
    $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: $("#scroll-" + page_id).offset().top
    }, 2000)
}
```

});

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged.  Please add a simple explanation.

Answer (score 0):

There is a jquery plugin for this. It scrolls document to a specific element, so that it would be perfectly in the middle of viewport. It also supports animation easings so that the scroll effect would look super smooth. Check out [AnimatedScroll.js](http://plugins.jquery.com/animatedscrolljs/).

Comment: I would avoid using a plugin like this, when the real answer is natively supported. `$('html,body').animate({scrollTop:x},t);` is plenty correct, no need to add an unnecessary plugin to your page's network tab.

Comment: You're absolutely right, except that this plugin is able to scroll to any document element, so that it would be exactly in the middle of window viewport.

Comment: The problem is, that's still really easy without any plugins. It's just a matter of scrolling to `($e.offset().top+($e.height()/2))-($(window).height()/2)`, or in English, `"elementCenter minus halfViewportHeight"`. Right?

Comment: right, as far as you wouldn't mind to write so much code every time you need to scroll to a specific element

Comment: @EugeneTiurin You could just create a custom function, taking the element as a parameter.

Comment: but how exactly does jQuery achieve smooth scroll?