# Button to scroll

Tags: jquery, scroll

I am trying to scroll the text which is inside .text, when I click to .down. I have a simple text with overflow hidden. I have the example here: http://jsbin.com/ofaquh/1/edit

I have been looking to the jQuery scrollTo function, but I think I don't know how to use it well:

```
$(function(){      
    $(".down").click(function() {
        $(".text").scrollTo(20);
    });
})
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery animate scroll](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8047454/jquery-animate-scroll)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.scrollTo()` is actually a plugin.

You can use `.animate()` and `scrollTop` and achieve the same result:

```
$(".down").click(function() {
    $(".text").animate({ scrollTop: 200 });
});
```

[jsBin Demo](http://jsbin.com/ofaquh/9/edit)

Comment: [`.scrollTo` was vanilla JS first.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.scrollTo) I still confuse them all the time.

Comment: The best thing about using `.animate` is that you can use `'+=20'` instead of `20` to keep scrolling. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/jg4AS/)

Comment: Oops accidentally deleted my comment lol. Yeah I love the ability to add/subtract on the fly.

Comment: You answer is just great! It is so clean and easy. I added here the up button too: http://jsbin.com/ofaquh/12/edit Is there a way as easy as this to add a bar or reference to know the length of the text?

Comment: I have no idea. I just want to learn new things and improve this

Comment: Just do `overflow-y:scroll;` instead of `overflow:hidden;`. The scrolling functionality will still work, and you'll have a scrollbar that way.

Comment: Yes I know that, but I mean to design my own scroll. For instance to make just one small dot to indicate the position of the text

Comment: You'd have to do a bunch of javascript yourself, or use a plugin like this: http://www.myjqueryplugins.com/jquery-plugin/jscrollbar

Answer (score 3):

See fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/AWQzg/

Use `scrollTop()`

```
$(function(){

$(".down").click(function() {
    $(".text").scrollTop(20);
});

})
```

​

See : http://jsfiddle.net/AWQzg/1/ for repeated scroll of 20px on each click

```
$(function(){

$(".down").click(function() {
    $(".text").scrollTop($(".text").scrollTop() + 20);
});

})
```

​

Comment: Your answer is very good, thank you. Thanks to you I could do the up button too: http://jsfiddle.net/AWQzg/3/ Is it possible to make a complete scroll bar in such a easy way?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're using the scrollTo plugin I think you want to use jQuery's [`scrollTop`](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) function.

Ex: `$(".text").scrollTop(20);`

Or, in response to your question in the comments, try:

```
var move = 20;     
$(".down").click(function() {
    $(".text").scrollTop(move);
        move += 20;
});
```

Comment: That's it! And how can I scroll 20px each time I click?

Comment: Change your function to increment the scrollTop with a variable. See my updated answer and this jsbin http://jsbin.com/ofaquh/11/edit.

Comment: Your solution is great. I tried to add the up button but there is something estrange when it arrives to the bottom, it cannot go up again: http://jsbin.com/ofaquh/12/edit

Comment: Sorry I gave you the adaptation of another answer. The jsbin with the two buttons with your code is this: http://jsbin.com/ofaquh/13/edit This is the one that has the problem.

Comment: Looks like you accepted an answer for this question. Do you still need help?

Comment: No, I don't need any help. I just explained why I selected another option. Anyway, your option was really good and quite close. Thank you!